# How to use escape characters in string templates in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I want to use escape characters in a template string as shown below. However, it does not process the escape characters but rather prints the string as it is.

```
string msgTemplate = string `ABC\nDEF\nGHI`
```

I know the escape characters are working in Ballerina strings (without templates) `string msg = "ABC\nDEF\nGHI"`. Is there a way to have escape characters in template strings similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ballerina, string templates are designed to allow the user to input a string as it is. In the above string template example, the newline characters are not expanded but interpreted as literal characters. Hence, escape characters are not processed unless they are interpolated properly. So, you can use interpolations to have escape characters in a string template as shown below.

```
string msgTemplate = string `ABC${"\n"}DEF${"\n"}GHI`;
```